# LDAP connection without providing username and password in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, principalcontext

I have a project using .NET Core. I have a problem with authenticating `LDAP` connection. In `.net framework`, it's possible to authenticate `LDAP` connection without username and password but it's seems unable to work in `.NET Core`.

Now how do you authenticate a connection in `LDAP` using `PrincipalContext` without providing username and password? In .NET Core? Thanks in advance .

Below is my sample code:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

....
using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "123.123.123.123"))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "hreyes"))
    {
        if(user != null)
        {
            string email = user.EmailAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is also know as windows integrated security

Comment: you need to tell us what `type` of project this is...asp.net core for example?

Comment: yes sorry. It's a asp .net core.